for looping PHP syntax to Smarty Syntax
I have a PPH syntax from prestashop file:
<select name="deadline" id="deadline" onclick="dead_line_all()">    
<option value="235959" selected="selected">'.$this->l('NONE').'</option>';  
for($hours=0; $hours<24; $hours++)      
for($mins=0; $mins<60; $mins+=30)   
$this->_html .= '
<option value="'.str_pad($hours,2,'0',STR_PAD_LEFT).''.str_pad($mins,2,'0',STR_PAD_LEFT).'00">               '.str_pad($hours,2,'0',STR_PAD_LEFT).':'.str_pad($mins,2,'0',STR_PAD_LEFT).' 
</option>'; 
$this->_html .= ' </select>

How to change it into smarty syntax in the smarty template (xxx.tpl)?

Have you researched or tried anything. Where are you stuck? Is there any specific reason we shouldn't just point you to the smarty documentation about loops? What actual problem do you need our help with? See also [ask]

Their are two ways to do this.
First simple assign this select html to smarty variable in php file and print in xxx.tpl
php file
<?php
$html .= '<select name="deadline" id="deadline" 
      onclick="dead_line_all()">';'
      $html .= '<option value="235959" selected="selected">--Select--</option>';
     for($hours=0; $hours<24; $hours++){
        for($mins=0; $mins<60; $mins+=30){
       $html .= '<option value="'.str_pad($hours,2,'0',STR_PAD_LEFT).''.str_pad($mins,2,'0',STR_PAD_LEFT).'00">'.str_pad($hours,2,'0',STR_PAD_LEFT).':'.str_pad($mins,2,'0',STR_PAD_LEFT).'</option>';
        }
     }
$html .= '</select>';

$smarty->assign('select',$html);
?>

xxx.tpl template file
 


    {$select}



this will print select html in template file.
2.Second option in  code within template xxx.tpl file

<select name="deadline" id="deadline" onclick="dead_line_all()">
   <option value="235959" selected="selected">Select</option>
  {for $hour=0 to 24}
   <option value="{$hour|str_pad:2:0:STR_PAD_LEFT}:30">{$hour|str_pad:2:0:STR_PAD_LEFT}:30</option>
   <option value="{$hour|str_pad:2:0:STR_PAD_LEFT}:60">{$hour|str_pad:2:0:STR_PAD_LEFT}:60</option>
  {/for}
 </select>


also you need to create new smarty modifier plugin for str_pad function.
<?php

function smarty_modifier_str_pad($string,$length,$pad_string,$pad_type) {
    return str_pad($string,$length,$pad_string,$pad_type);
}

$smarty->registerPlugin(Smarty\Smarty::PLUGIN_MODIFIER, 'str_pad', 'smarty_modifier_str_pad');

?>

for more info on adding modifiers
https://smarty-php.github.io/smarty/stable/api/extending/modifiers/
second example is for latest smarty library
